# Change Nested Field Name in glue dynamic frame

Tags: amazon-web-services, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, aws-glue

I have a glue dynamic frame with following schema.

```
root
|-- grade: struct
|    |-- num: string
|-- name: struct
|    |-- first: string
```

I want to change the name of num to score.
I use the the rename_field function.

```
df = df.rename_field("grade.num", "grade.score")
```

But the method does not seem to work. I know a solution in spark using cast function but is there any way using glue dynamic frame? Is changing names of nested columns even possible using dynamic frame inbuilt functions?

Comment: Maybe this one can help you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45970673/aws-glue-rename-field-does-not-work-after-relationalize

Anyway, I'll suggest to convert it to a dataframe.

Comment: I think the rename_field is misleading in glue. It can only change the names of main fields and can denest nested fields. It cannot change the names of nesed fields.